# Hide cell value based on some condition - jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to hide cell value based on certain condition, say cell value is < 20

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a formatter

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
...
   colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', index:'price', width:60, align:"center", editable: true, formatter:currencyFmatter},
      ...
   ]
...
});

function currencyFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   if (cellvalue < 20)
    return "";
   else
    return new_format_value
}
```

Reference:http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks for your response. I have tried formatter. but Some of these columns are editable and when I am using formatter, clicking on editable cell shows the html that is used to format the cell. Is there a way to hide the content and make the cells not editable.

Answer (score 0):

How about..

```
$('table td').each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  if(parseFloat($this.text()) < 20) {
    $this.css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Khior, I am using a jqGrid. I tried this approach. Seems to not work.

Comment: Ok, that's useful information! Have you checked out these pages? http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html Specifically, there's a section about row editing.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at demos. I actually need to use cellattr which I initially said I dont want to use, or may be formatter. I have been looking at similar posts and have gotten a bit closer to what I need to do but not there yet.